# When time is finished for Jquery count down how to popup and submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, form-submit, countdown

```js
var timer2 = "00:05";
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.demo').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
    alert('Success');
  }, 5000);

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo"></div>
<form id="form">
  <input name="hello" value="hello">
</form>
```

Hello i prepare a quiz countdown time with jquery, i want to popup that "Quiz is finished" and then submit the form when press "Ok" button.
This is my fiddle..

Answer (score 1):

You are loading a countdown you are not using and you need to move the submit into the if statement

I removed the countdown.js and test if both minutes and seconds are 0

not sure why you want to wait another 5 seconds to submit, but here you go:

```js
var timer2 = "00:05";
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
  $('.demo').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  if (minutes === 0 && seconds <= 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#form').submit();
      alert('Success');
    }, 5000);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo"></div>
<form id="form">
  <input name="hello" value="hello">
</form>
```